# React-Native Nested Navigation is causing 2 menus to appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently running into an issue trying to make a Shopping List app with React-Native. I am using React Navigation to handle the screens but I have run into an issue where if I click the Float Action Button on the Home Screen it will pop up the "I am the AddShoppingListForm", However when I open the next screen and click the button again that menu pops up as well as the menu that should pop up at the screen saying "I am the AddShoppingListItemForm" and they overlap each other.

How would I go about making sure the correct menu opens on the correct screen? I have the "isVisible" currently being stored in Redux to make it easier to change the value depending on how nested I am on the components, But I am not sure if this is correct way to go about doing this.

I tried to make a Overlay component that could act as a wrapper for the Menu component that gets passed there but I am not sure that is the correct way to go about doing that. Any advice would be greately appreciated.

Here is my snippets of code.

HomeScreen:

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const isVisible = useSelector(selectOverlayVisiblity);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    dispatch(
      setOverlayVisible(!isVisible)
    )
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Shopping List */}
      <ShoppingList navigation={navigation} />

      <PopupMenu menu={<AddShoppingListForm />} isVisible={isVisible} />

      {/* Action Button */}
      <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)" onPress={toggleOverlay} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

ListScreen:

```
export default function ShoppingListDetailScreen({ navigation }) {
  const currentlistitems = useSelector(selectCurrentList);
  const isVisible = useSelector(selectOverlayVisiblity);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    dispatch(
      setOverlayVisible(!isVisible)
    )
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>


      {currentlistitems.map(function (item) {
        return <ListItemComponent key={item.id} title={item.title} avatar_url={item.avatar_url} />;
      })}

      <PopupMenu isVisible={isVisible} menu={<AddShoppingListItemForm />} />

      {/* Action Button */}
      <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)" onPress={toggleOverlay} />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Popup Menu:

```
export default function PopupMenu({ navigation, isVisible, menu }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const toggleOverlay = () => {
    dispatch(setOverlayVisible(!isVisible));
  };

  // console.log('MENU >>>', menu);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Overlay */}
      {Platform.OS === "web" ? (
        <WebModal isVisible={isVisible} menu={menu} />
      ) : (
        <MobileModal isVisible={isVisible} menu={menu} />
      )}
      {/* End of Overlay */}
    </View>
  );
}
```

ShoppingListForm:

```
function AddShoppingListForm() {

    const route = useRoute();

    console.log('AddShoppingListLitem >>', route.name);

    return (
        <View>
            {route.name === 'Home' &&
                <Text style={{color: "#fff"}}>I am the AddShoppingListForm</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

ShoppingListItemForm:

```
function AddShoppingListItemForm() {

    const route = useRoute();

    console.log('AddShoppingListLitem >>', route.name);

    return (
        <View>
            {route.name === 'List' &&
                <Text>I am the ShoppingListItemForm</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Here are example images so you can see what I mean:

[image: This is the first menu how it should be]

[image: This is the second image showing the first menu there too.]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue I was having by removing the isVisible from Redux and rather using useState to just store the isVisible in that specific screen instead of across the app.